# Generating IkFast MoveIt Plugin for UR5 from 2 different URDF's

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to the MoveIt tutorial on IkFast Kinematics Solver, I managed to generate a plugin for UR5 using the urdf files in the ur_description from the generic ros-industrial/universal_robot github. However, I am using the new ur robot driver. That requires the urdf from the specific gitbub of fmauch/universal_robot. When I used the urdf from there, the docker image generates alot of errors. I assume both ur5.urdf.xacro are describing the same manipulator and should produce the same Ik solver but it obviously does not!

Any idea which of them should be used.

Thank you very much for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359209/generating-ikfast-moveit-plugin-for-ur5-from-2-different-urdf%27s/) by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2020-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I assume both ur5.urdf.xacro are describing the same manipulator and should produce the same Ik solver but it obviously does not!

that would not be a(n) (entirely) correct assumption.

The files in `ros-industrial/universal_robot` model the kinematics of a single robot, which is almost guaranteed *not* to correspond to the kinematics of your specific robot.

The difference would be in the kinematic calibration data.

The files in `fmauch/universal_robot` have been extended to allow you to *import* the calibration from your robot, which will then update `link` length and `joint` offsets such that the resulting URDF corresponds 100% with the kinematic structure of your specific robot.

So while from a high-level those files model the same robot *type*, the URDFs which will be uploaded to `robot_description` are actually different.

---

Edit:

> does this mean, if I want to use a self generated IkFast plugin for Moveit to use, I should go through the ur robot ros driver to the point where I get the calibration data from the robot first. Then use that data to generate a urdf with the calibration data to use the docker image to generate the IkFast plugin before using the moveit setup assistant to generate the moveit config suit for use?

If you want the IKFast plugin to be generated while taking the calibration data of *your* robot into account, then: yes.

> At the same time, I would like to ask how is the joint_limited situation for ur5? You and others started to discuss this issue back from 2014. Have you come to a conclusion that we do not need to limit the joints to just +-pi except for the elble?
> And a further question, is the vel_joint_trajectory_controller of the new ur robot driver ready for use yet?

These seem unrelated to the question you ask in your OP.

It would be better to post new questions -- after verifying these have not been asked before.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-11**:
The need to use the `fmauch` fork will be removed, as the files in `ros-industrial/universal_robot` will be updated to include the necessary changes to support importing kinematic calibration data.

This is already started and part of [ros-industrial/universal_robot#448](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues/448).

The current progress can be seen in [ros-industrial/universal_robot@melodic-devel-staging](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/tree/melodic-devel-staging).

Work to make `UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver` compatible with this is in [UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver#97](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/pull/97).

**Comment by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) on 2020-08-11**:
@gvdhoorn does this mean, if I want to use a self generated IkFast plugin for Moveit to use, I should go through the ur robot ros driver to the point where I get the calibration data from the robot first. Then use that data to generate a urdf with the calibration data to use the docker image to generate the IkFast plugin before using the moveit setup assistant to generate the moveit config suit for use?
At the same time, I would like to ask how is the joint_limited situation for ur5? You and others started to discuss this issue back from 2014. Have you come to a conclusion that we do not need to limit the joints to just +-pi except for the elble?
And a further question, is the vel_joint_trajectory_controller of the new ur robot driver ready for use yet?

**Comment by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) on 2020-08-12**:
When I use the urdf from the fmauch fork and trying to generate the IkFast plugin, I got the following:

```
openravepy.databases.inversekinematics: testik, success rate: 0.000000, wrong solutions: 0.000000, no solutions: 1.000000, missing solution: 0.000000
Created /tmp/ikfast.rKmGra/.openrave/kinematics.4bd8292d934c988a06151a7ad63f3388/ikfast0x10000049.Transform6D.0_1_2_3_4_5.cpp
```

So, I will interpret it as complete failure, with success rate:0; no solutions: 1.0. What could have gone wrong?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-12**:
I have no idea.

**Comment by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) on 2020-08-12**:
Thank you very much for all your help so far. I will then try the melodic-devel-staging and report back.